# dnf cannot install local rpm file: "No package matches"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install an RPM file in a Docker image with the Amazon Linux 2023 parent image. This parent image only contains `dnf`, not `yum`. Specifically, I am trying to install R4.3.2 as below:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:latest-x86_64

ENV R_VERSION=4.3.2

RUN dnf -y install wget

RUN wget https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/rhel-9/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm 

RUN dnf -y install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

This last step fails with `No package matches 'R-4.3.2-1-1.x86_64.rpm'`. Running a bash shell in the container, I tried to specify the path exactly, even moving the rpm into a separate directory, but the error persists. The file is definitely there, but either `dnf` doesn't see it or it doesn't consider it a local file.

What *does* work is using `rpm -i`. However, without the dependency detection of `dnf` I'm forced to manually specify and install the dependencies.

Is there some way to hint to `dnf` that it should be looking for a local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a restriction of [the particular `dnf` installed on Amazon Linux 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-amazon-linux-2023-runtime-for-aws-lambda/):

> Note that `microdnf` does not support all options of `dnf`. For example, you cannot install a remote `rpm` using the rpm’s URL or install a local `rpm` file. Instead, you can use the `rpm` command directly to install such packages.

A trick to get around this is to use `rpm` to determine the file's dependencies, and then to pass those to `dnf`.

```
dnf install -y `rpm -qR R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm | tr '\n' ' ' `
```

For anyone finding this through a web search, the following lines are needed for the Dockerfile. The last part is optional, but it deletes the rpm after installation to save a little space:

```
RUN dnf install -y `rpm -qR R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm | tr '\n' ' ' `

RUN rpm -i R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
    && rm R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
```